# How to make an image display on first page load, but not subsequent loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, pageload

I am running three photos in a js slideshow function, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have the first image in the slideshow display only when the side is FIRST loaded, but not when an user navigates to other pages in the site. If possible, I would like subsequent page loads to begin at the second or third image in the slideshow.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(function () {
    setTimeout(playSlideShow, 6400);

  function playSlideShow() {

    var currImgContainer = $('.showImg');
    if (!$(currImgContainer).hasClass('lastImg')) {
        $('.showImg').removeClass('showImg').next().addClass('showImg');
        setTimeout(playSlideShow, 6400);
    }
    if (!$(currImgContainer).hasClass('secImg')) {
        setTimeout(playSlideShow, 4500);
    }
   }
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideShow" id="slideshow">
   <div class="showImg">
     <img src="img1.gif" />
   </div>
   <div class="secImg">
     <img src="img2.gif" />
   </div>
   <div class="lastImg">
     <img src="img3.gif"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i would sugest adding a cookie or using localStorage

Comment: also you should load the images via JS, its much easier to control the loading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing data in the browser from previous page loads is pretty complicated and time consuming for a task like this.

Another option would be to set the carousel to display a different image based on which page it's being loaded on.

First, you can add a data attribute to a consistent element in each of your pages like this:

```
  <body data-slideNum="2">
    <div class="slideShow" id="slideshow">
     <div class="showImg">
       <img src="img1.gif" />
     </div>
     <div class="secImg">
       <img src="img2.gif" />
     </div>
     <div class="lastImg">
       <img src="img3.gif"/>
     </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

The, you can write some javascript to check that attribute on page load and set the carousel image number accordingly. Something like this:

```
var startingSlide = $('body').attr('data-slideNum');
```

Which, in this case would set 'startingSlide' equal to '2'.

Comment: This actually did give me an idea for a work around which seems to be doing what I want it to so far. The one limitation is that I can't apply a separate attribute to actual pages (as in, websiteurl.com/page/2), considering this is a blog. Any thoughts?

Comment: You wouldn't need to add a param to the URL - just to any element on the page, as long as that element is consistently present on each page of the blog. Do you have the ability to add attributes to any elements, like the data-slideNum attribute I posted in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use jQuery Cookie.
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

On page load, check if the cookie is set, if not display the image and set it, if it is set don't do anything (assuming image is hidden by default).

Something like this:

```
if($.cookie('image') == undefined)
    $('#image').show();
    $.cookie('image', 'shown');
}
```